# Jquery Innerfade plugin over riding css

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Jquery plugin innerfade is over riding my css styling of margin.
Can't realign it.

**CSS:**

```
.changer{
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='changer'>
    <p>Am a <span class='highlight1'>Web Maker </span></p>

    <p>Am a <span class='highlight1'>Windows Phone Dev</span></p>

    <p>Am a <span class='highlight1'>Reverse Engineer</span></p>

    <p>Am an <span class='highlight1'>UI/UX Lover </span></p>

    <p>Am a <span class='highlight1'>Geek</span></p>

    <p>Am a <span class='highlight1'>Human </span></p>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.changer').innerfade({
            animationtype: 'slide',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 2000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });
});
```

Please note that this code wont work until you add innerfade plugin so please note that if you are testing the code.
thank you.

Comment: Well then try adding `!important` to your `css`!!

Comment: @guruprasad Rao.,
Tried it already,
no go with that.

Comment: I don't see any problem with margins when using this plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/37zutmsk/. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dekkard you are missing the plugin here boss. i had the problem using the original inner fade plugin

Comment: Can you provide a link where the "original" plugin can be downloaded from?

Comment: @dekkard
https://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/

Comment: This is the same plugin that is loaded into the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/37zutmsk/ (compare the source code if you wish). Do you use all of its bundled CSS files on your page as well?

Comment: @dekkard i checked it., but seems that animation dont work in jsfiddle,
once it start working the position is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `innerFade.js` plugin find below line [May be Line 83]:

```
// Set the z-index from highest to lowest (20, 19, 18...), hide everything and set position as absolute
for (var i = 0; i < $fade_object.elements.length; i++) {
      $($fade_object.elements[i]).hide(0).css('z-index', String($fade_object.elements.length-i)).css('position', 'absolute');
}
```

and change the content inside `for loop` as below:

```
$($fade_object.elements[i]).hide(0).css('z-index', String($fade_object.elements.length-i)).css('position', 'absolute').css('text-align','center').css('width','100%');
```

What I am suggesting here is, *the div doesn't take up all the available horizontal space when absolutely positioned. Explicitly setting the width to 100% will solve the problem*. So you need to modify the plugin and set 2 more attributes to your `position:absolute` contents, `text-align:center` and `width:100%`. That will do the trick.

**The above solution is tested and then posted here.**

Comment: the following is the only for loop. is it what you meant?
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                $(elements[i]).css('z-index', String(elements.length-i)).css('position', 'absolute').hide();
            };

Comment: No @AlokRajasukumaran. There are multiple for loops. In **[this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a6ouLht8/)** I have copied and pasted the whole plugin!! check for the line I have said or search for the comment mentioned above in the code - `Set the z-index from.....` You will find it. Change that!!

Comment: ok this was not the plugin i was using. issue was that brother. let me try updating my codes now

Comment: That don't work for me.,
its showing like the element is undefined now :(

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran.. Here is the complete **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a6ouLht8/1/)** and here is the **[result](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a6ouLht8/1/embedded/result/)** which works fine!! I have mentioned in comments in fiddle `js` part what to do!! Try it!!

Comment: no change. here is my fiddle which i use now.
https://jsfiddle.net/alokraj68/99cbjyxd/

result:
https://jsfiddle.net/alokraj68/99cbjyxd/embedded/result/

Comment: Here is your **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/99cbjyxd/1/)** . You were having extra `});` at the end which was need only if you had included your complete code in `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: ya it started working with the same alignment issue and now the animation is cluttery. its struck at tyms. :(

Comment: what alignment issue?? Isn't it centered now?? and what animation cluttery you are seeing?? :o

Comment: The whole animation is too slow and it shows up like iy\ts coming and going. and ya the alignment issue resolved by giving relative in innerfade js.

Comment: Can you show how it was before so that I can compare and try making changes!!

Comment: Okay. resolved everything now.
changing to relative helped my css issue. and the slow animation was tackled by changing to original innerfade js